# Титулы, звания и научные степени в роли обращений

Tags: прописная-строчная

Скажите, пожалуйста, если я обращаюсь к собеседнику по титулу/званию/научной степени, какое   написание - со строчной или с прописной буквы? - данных наименований корректно в этом случае?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С прописной буквы пишутся все слова в именах собственных ОСОБОЙ ЗНАЧИМОСТИ - это официальные названия высших должностей и званий страны, а также названия, относящиеся к церкви. В официальной обстановке обращения к таким лицам также пишутся с прописной буквы, например:

Ваше Превосходительство, господин Посол, что бы Вы хотели пожелать российско-китайским отношениям? Ваше Превосходительство, уважаемый господин Президент! Господин Министр! 
Ваше Святейшество, Святейший Патриарх Московский и всея Руси, возлюбленный брат и сослужитель, господин Кирилл!

Но: "Что-нибудь выпьете, господин министр?" "Добрый день, господин профессор". Во всех остальных случаях обращения будут писаться со строчной буквы.

Comment: Спасибо, воспользуюсь.